# Graph like illustration in website

Tags: javascript

I have visited the site https://www.collectiveip.com/ and there is a very interesting graph-like object on the homepage which responds to mouse movement.

Can somebody suggest as to what is the object and what libraries are used to create similar objects?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you right-click and look at the source, there are plenty of hints that the graph is drawn using [three.js](http://threejs.org/).

three.js is a 3D drawing library that simplifies coding WebGL scenes.

If you look at the source further, you can find that all the graphics is drawn in a javascript file called `threejsgraph-(some_big_random_hash).js`. Paste it into a pretty printer (google "javascript pretty printer") to make it more readable.

Basically the code creates a lot of random sprites with lines (path) connecting them then animate the camera based on mouse movement.